# Как воспроизвести музыку в фоновом режиме?

Tags: python, python-3.x, аудио, pygame

У меня получилось воспроизвести музыку с помощью pygame, но она блокирует основной поток. Нашел в интернете инфу о том что с помощью pygame нельзя воспроизводить музыку в фоновом режиме, так вот - есть ли альтернативные способы?

```
# Soundtracks
music = pg.mixer.music
st1 = ['sounds/st1.mp3', 120]

def s_play(sound, timeout):
    music.load(sound)
    music.play()
    time.sleep(timeout)
s_play(st1[0], st1[1])
print('Какой-то текст') # не отображается до конца воспроизведения
# Soundtracks
```

Comment: а если музыку запусть в отдельном threading ? фпс просядет?

Comment: Я знаю только как запустить две функции в разных потоках, но как запустить определенную функцию в определенном потоке из другой функции, не знаю.

Comment: Кстати кто-то уже пытался так сделать, и ему ответили что pygame это не позволяет.